# php scandir: prevent parent folder

Tags: javascript, php

I have done a simple ajax file browser. The space on the server is multi user so every user must have the access only to it's folder.

```
/all_folders/user1
/all_folders/user2
...
```

With scandir i got '.' and '..' : with this last option he can go to the parent folder. How to prevent this "hotkey" ??

since I send the folder list from php to javascript i tried (in php) removing with unset the value with index 1 from the array of the scandir results but after this '.' doens't work so the user can't go to the previous folder.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show your codes? You can filter away `.` and `..` when you use `scandir()`

Comment: I only want to filter .. but if I filter it with unset or array_diff then . doesn't work to go to the previous folder. Is this normal ??

Comment: You are giving PHP access to other users? Why?

Comment: it's for university project but I don't give php access to other user....

Comment: If they have write access, this could be a problem without a solution. If they just need to use JavaScript use CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php
    $dir = scandir('/path');

    if($baseFolder)
    {
        $key=array_search('..',$dir);
        array_splice($dir, $key ,1);
    }
?>
```

Then you will have all folders except '..' and also the keys will be in order..

Hope this helps.